# Synonym for "media item"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I am looking for a synonym for "media item" by which I mean a single photo, article, video, document, etc. I need *one* term as a handle for one of any of these types of items.

I am honing my domain vocabulary for communicating with public affairs clients on software development projects.  I find "media item" a little clunky, and I am wondering if there's a better handle out there.

Unfortunately, "publication" can't do, as this leads to some confusion given the way I need to use the term "publish" for non-media items.

Comment: I'm getting good answers here. One more thing I should have specified though: media items contrast with other objects in these contexts in that they have a salient point-in-time aspect -- that is, there is a publication date associated with them that is important to their context. Other objects in this domain can be "published", but the non- "media-items" can last indefinitely, while media-items have a relatively short turnover/shelf-life.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I refer to these in my professional life as "assets".

Comment: +1; The term "asset" is also used to describe the amount of these types of items are associated with a project or product (i.e. [World of Warcraft](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/90/why-is-it-so-hard-to-develop-a-mmo/239#239))

Answer (score 6):

In my projects I usually go with resources.

Answer (score 1):

If it had to be one word, I might describe it as a "work." A one word description of all things published is not something easy to say without really broad, possibly oversimplified terms.

Answer (score 1):

If you are discussing these 'media items' in terms of things you want to include in a page, or something similar, then possibly "**insert**".

If they are things that you or a client of yours has created, I'm thinking, '**opus**'.

Comment: This one feels kind of close (+1 for that), and it's leading me to consider "attachment." But neither is quite right. See my own comment on the question. thx.

Answer (score 1):

Since *media* is plural, could you just use *[medium](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/medium#Noun)*? Per Wiktionary:

> A format for communicating or presenting information.

Comment: medium (1), media (many) -- hmmm. I'll put that on the candidate list (+1 vote)