# Is there a word that refers to discrete pieces of visual content that could be either still or moving images?

Tags: single-word-requests, countable-nouns

I've searched for this here and elsewhere but not been able to find it. I'm looking for a word that refers to discrete pieces of visual content that could be either still or moving images. That is, the word should encompass both "photographs" and "film clips." So if you were referring to a group of three photographs and two film clips, you could say you have five of these things: "I just sent you five _____, including three photos and two film clips."

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: **Montage, Collage**?

Comment: May be related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19682/synonym-for-media-item

Answer (score 1):

You could refer to them collectively as ***media*** or ***mixed media***, and when referring to individual items (as when saying you've sent five of them) you could say ***I just sent you five pieces of mixed media.***

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_media

Answer (score 1):

**Visuals**, according to Oxford dict:

> noun
> (usually visuals)
>
> A picture, piece of film, or display used to illustrate or accompany something:
>
> ‘the music should fit the visuals’
> ‘colour visuals of today’s models

Answer (score 0):

**Still**

> Photography. noting, pertaining to, or used for making single
>   photographs, as opposed to a motion picture.

Also see here for a debate about [meaning](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/movie-stills.2062631/)

You could say for instance you have 'five stills' which would mean you had 5 individual pictures.

As the definition states you can also use this when referring to single photographs.

So I think this may well suit your meaning.